# Why are environment variables not resolved when double-clicking .desktop file?

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, environment-variables, java, .desktop

I have a Java application which is launched by a shell script.
The first part of the shell script is to resolve the Java location by looking at `$JAVA_HOME`.

The shell script is working well if launched from the terminal but it fails if launched by double-clicking the `.desktop` file which contains the following

```
Exec=/bin/sh "/opt/HO/HO" %U
```

Looking at the logs it seems the error occurs because `$JAVA_HOME` returns nothing when the script is launched that way.

I tried to replace `/bin/sh` by `/bin/bash` but it also fails.

Any idea why environment variables are not found that way? What should I do?

Comment: where are you setting `JAVA_HOME` ? `.bashrc` ?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/542152/desktop-file-with-bashrc-environment

Comment: Incidentally, and because I think everyone should know about this, this may be the most useful resource on the internet: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables
thanks @akasolace, for the tip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Ubuntu documentation [1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables):

> Shell config files such as ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, and
> ~/.bash_login are often suggested for setting environment variables.
> While this may work on Bash shells for programs started from the
> shell, variables set in those files are not available by default to
> programs started from the graphical environment in a desktop session.

Hence, the fix was to declare `$JAVA_HOME` in `.profile` and to log in again.

(thank you @plumo, for pointing me into the right direction)